# How can I get my tables' caption and numbering to look more like that of an image

Tags: tables, graphics, captions

[image: my table with caption]

For some reason my tables' caption looks really odd, its in a weird font and size and centered, and its numbering is in roman numerals and bulky unlike my figures of which the captions and numberings look fine. This was done in overleaf in a letterpaper template with graphicx installed.

[image: The code for the table]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add the code directly into your question.

Comment: How exactly the caption text looks like might depend on the documentclass you use as well as on the settings of the `caption` package. Please also clarify: Is the sreeenshot the unwanted output or does it represent how you want your captions to look like. If it is the current output, please also add a sketch of how you want your captions to look like.

Comment: somewhere you or the document class yiu are using has specified `\scshape` (caps and small caps) for table captions, but it is in code you have not shown.